# How do I set a new reference point within Eagle CAD?

Tags: eaglecad

How do I change the reference point in Eagle CAD for placing parts correctly? I'm using MARK  but it did not set the new mark point as a reference. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: MARK just defines an additional reference relative to the main origin. You have to group and move all components as Scott suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out how to do this. I'm using Eagle 6.5 fwiw.

MARK (C -7.5 -4.1);

Sets the origin to (-7.5 -4.1). The C says "left click". It also works if you type MARK and then actually left click with the mouse where you want the reference to be.

The manual and some docs on MIT's website are definitely worth a read here and there. For example: http://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/25.htm

To set the origin back to the natural origin, you just type MARK;

Comment: That doesn't move the origin point, it would just create new mark !!!!

Answer (score 8):

You have to group and move all components. However, I would not recommend moving the componets with a mouse, as the selected grid might not fit.

Instead, use the command `move (>0 0) (dX dY)` to move the group a specific distance.

*Example*: `move (>0 0) (-10 0)`, to move the group 10mil to the left (if the grid unit is set to mil).

Comment: @vicatcu Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't see how it answers the question... nothing personal

Comment: @vicatcu The question is aboout "placing parts correctly".

Comment: I see what you mean... I'll retract the down vote. It's just disconnected with the question title.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to group everything and move the whole group.   Make sure all the layers are displayed first.